# Rewrite SUBQUERY UNION SELECT into JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

In my query I ran into a problem where `FULLTEXT INDEX` cannot be asigned to a `DERIVED TABLE`, which appears to be normal.

Example demonstrates that `data` cannot become indexed as `FULLTEXT`, but `content`, `text`, and `record` columns are already indexed as `FULLTEXT` as they are in 'real' tables

```
SELECT `data` FROM SELECT(
   SELECT `content` as `data` FROM `table1`
   UNION SELECT `text` as `data` FROM `table2`
   UNION SELECT `record` as `data` FROM `table3`
) as `search`
```

In my actual code I use to `SELECT MATCH() AGAINST()` scores from tables and I UNION them together to get a `score` for each table, these UNIONS are subqueries and first level (main) SELECT then SELECTS those UNIONS as derived table and calculates a score from them, however this is not done. An error occurs saying that a reference is not having an INDEX. (Just like in an above example).

These is a reason why I decided to ask if it is possible to achieve my goal with JOINS.

Here is my actual (working) code:

```
SELECT *,MATCH(`data`) AGAINST('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as `relevance` 
FROM (                  
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_pages' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_pages` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`, `id`,'tmp_news' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`,`content`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_news` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_comments' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`, `content`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` FROM `tmp_comments` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`, `content`) AGAINST('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`manufacturer`,' ',`model`,' ',`location`,' ',`other`,' ',`contact`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_auction_auto' as `table`,
        MATCH(`manufacturer`,`model`,`location`,`other`,`contact`) AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_auction_auto` 
        WHERE MATCH(`manufacturer`,`model`,`location`,`other`,`contact`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword')
) as `search` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

I would like to know if it is possible to turn this piece into `JOIN` type of query, plus make it function as expected. If so, I would kindly ask how to do it.

Comment: how are all of these tables related?  Without knowing that it would be difficult to say how you could join them all together.

Comment: they are not related by their columns all. assume that those contain data that does not need to be linked to other tables. thanks for interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could do this as a JOIN since the tables are unrelated.  However, you should be able to get rid of your error by simply omitting the `relevance` column from your outer query and ordering by `score`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (                  
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_pages' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_pages` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`, `id`,'tmp_news' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`,`content`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_news` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,' ',`content`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_comments' as `table`, 
        MATCH(`title`, `content`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` FROM `tmp_comments` 
        WHERE MATCH(`title`, `content`) AGAINST('keyword')
        UNION 
        SELECT CONCAT(`manufacturer`,' ',`model`,' ',`location`,' ',`other`,' ',`contact`) as `data`,`id`,'tmp_auction_auto' as `table`,
        MATCH(`manufacturer`,`model`,`location`,`other`,`contact`) AGAINST ('keyword') AS `score` 
        FROM `tmp_auction_auto` 
        WHERE MATCH(`manufacturer`,`model`,`location`,`other`,`contact`) 
        AGAINST ('keyword')
) as `search` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Comment: Yes I know, I have done this before and it's not actually correct. I assume current MySQL version doesn't support what I need and people use Solr, lucene, etc. nowadays, which I cannot use because of client's server.

P.S. If you'd like to know why this is not a solution read as follows, otherwise thanks for getting me confident about `JOIN` here.

`score` is calculated per table, not per whole selection. What we want is collection of all records with a score calculated among these all results. Not collection of records with scores done in their tables and combined as if it was among tables.

Comment: @tmpmember - I think what you say there makes sense.  You could combine these scores as a SUM() or something, but you are correct that ultimately a tool like Lucene would be much better for the kind of searching you are trying to do here.